FIS_AUTH_ERROR in Firebase Messaging when publishing app on Google Play Store - Compose Multiplatform
I'm encountering an issue while trying to publish my Compose Multiplatform app on the Google Play Store. The app works perfectly in release mode on my devices, but it gets rejected when I try to upload the app bundle to the store. The error causing the rejection is a crash related to Firebase Cloud Messaging, specifically a "FIS_AUTH_ERROR."
    Exception java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 

java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken (FirebaseMessaging.java)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
Caused by java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:9)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken (FirebaseMessaging.java)
Caused by java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse (GmsRpc.java:332)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0 (GmsRpc.java:343)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzy.execute (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.2.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0)
  at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zzd (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.2.0)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)

This error occurs when trying to retrieve the Firebase Cloud Messaging token (FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken). The specific issue is related to Firebase Installations, but the app works fine in release mode on my own devices. However, the problem occurs only when publishing the app bundle to the store.
What I’ve tried so far:
Verified that google-services.json is correctly set up.
Checked the Firebase Cloud Messaging API on Google Cloud Console.
Confirmed that SHA-1 fingerprints are configured correctly in Firebase.
Made sure that all Firebase dependencies are up to date.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? What steps can I take to resolve the "FIS_AUTH_ERROR" and prevent the app from crashing during the Play Store review process?
